# HTML5/JS/jQuery: On invalid input, mark a different (arbitrary) element as invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to create one of those standard new password forms, where you type the new password once and then a second time to confirm. I would like it so that once you blur away from these fields, if they don't match, *both* will be marked invalid, as in the following scenario:

1. User enters password `abc` into `#newpassword1`.
2. User tabs to `#newpassword2`.
3. User enters password `def` into `#newpassword2`.
4. User tabs away.
5. Validation detects a mismatch, and marks both `#newpassword1` *and* `#newpassword2` as invalid.

I know that i can mark the target of an event as invalid by using `e.target.setCustomValidity(...)`, but i don't understand JavaScript's event model very well and can't figure out how to mark a *different* element as invalid based on the event target's own invalidity.

This is the relevant excerpt of (non-working) code that i am trying to use:

```
if ( $('#newpassword1').val() != $('#newpassword2').val() ) {
    errorMessage = "The new passwords you've entered don't match.";

    $('#newpassword1, #newpassword2').setCustomValidity(errorMessage);
}
```

This seems like it should work, intuitively, but of course it does not. The error is simply `TypeError: $(...).setCustomValidity is not a function`.

Please note: I am not asking how to add a red ring or whatever to a field, i want it to actually *be* invalid (as in, have its `validity.valid` property return `false`).

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that `setCustomValidity` must be used against a native HTML object, and not a jQuery object, try `.get().setCustomValidity(errorMessage)`

Comment: I believe `$('#newpassword1, #newpassword2')[0].setCustomValidity(errorMessage);` will also work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the below code. You are getting that error because jQuery returns an array of selected objects and since `setCustomValidity` is supported by native input elements and not jquery objects, you are seeing that error.

```
$('#newpassword1, #newpassword2').each(function() {
    this.setCustomValidity(errorMessage)
});
```

Comment: I don't know why i didn't try that, i had actually run into this exact same issue once before. Thanks!

Comment: I placed this code in my `$(document).ready` function and now the message is shown even if the input is filled! @Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="cabinet_settings_header cabinet_header">Список регионов работы для выбора</div>            
            <div class="registration_region_select checkbox-group required">
                <?for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($regions); $i++):?>                    
                    <label for="region_id_<?=$regions[$i]['region_id']?>">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="region_id[]"  value="<?=$regions[$i]['region_id']?>" id="region_id_<?=$regions[$i]['region_id']?>" />
                        <?=$regions[$i]['name']?>
                    </label>
                <?endfor;?>
            </div>

<div class="cabinet_settings_header cabinet_header">Проверка выбора регионов работы (разрешмет отправку формы, если минимум 1 выбран)</div>            

        $('.checkbox-group.required input').on('change', function(){
            checkRegions();
        });


        function checkRegions(){

            checked_counter = $('.checkbox-group.required :checkbox:checked').length;            

            if(checked_counter > 0){
                $('.checkbox-group.required #region_id_2')[0].setCustomValidity('');

            }else{
                $('.checkbox-group.required #region_id_2')[0].setCustomValidity('Выберите хотябы 1 из вариантов');
            }
        }

$(document).ready(function() {

            checkRegions();


            $("form").submit(function(event){
                   if($('.checkbox-group.required :checkbox:checked').length <= 0 ){                        
                        $('.checkbox-group.required #region_id_2').focus();
                        event.preventDefault();

                    }


            })


        });
```

Comment: A giant, poorly formatted block of code with no explanation is never a good answer.